# Windows + VS2019 + CMake + CLion + Conan: How to enable C++20?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cmake, conan

I'm getting this error:

> C:.conan\7c4aa5\1\include\absl/meta/type_traits.h(622): error C2039: 'result_of': is not a member of 'std'

When trying to compile my project which includes [Abseil](https://abseil.io/).

If I click into where the error is coming from, I see:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
// std::result_of is deprecated (C++17) or removed (C++20)
template<typename> struct result_of;
template<typename F, typename... Args>
struct result_of<F(Args...)> : std::invoke_result<F, Args...> {};
#else
template<typename F> using result_of = std::result_of<F>;
#endif
```

And right there at the top is a hint, that `std::result_of` was removed in C++20.

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I have

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

So why isn't `__cplusplus >= 201703L` true? What sets that variable? How do I tell the compiler I really do want to use C++20?

I don't know if I need to convince Visual Studio 16/2019, or CMake, or CLion, or what. There's too many things in the toolchain, but I shall add some screenshots so you can see what my setup is and hopefully someone can point out what I'm missing.

[image]

[image]

My full `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
set(EXE mario4ever)
project(${EXE})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

add_executable(${EXE} src/bootstrap.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${EXE} ${CONAN_LIBS})

add_custom_command(
        TARGET ${EXE} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/resources $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${EXE}>/resources
        COMMENT "Copying shaders" VERBATIM
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got it to compile. The magic line was this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /std:c++20 /Zc:__cplusplus")
```

Add that to `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: FYI, there is a new set of build system integrations in Conan, that will achieve transparent integration, have a look at: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake.html. ``CMakeToolchain`` should be able to automatically define the C++ standard according to the Conan setting ``compiler.cppstd``.

Comment: @drodri I did find and play with that setting too actually, but couldn't get it to work. Added it to be 'profile'.

Comment: Then, it might be useful to file an issue to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues (specifically for the new CMakeToolchain integration, as it is the one moving forward, the ``cmake`` is consider legacy and will be removed in Conan 2.0)